# Lightweight Desktop APP with Node - is that possible?

Tags: node.js, desktop-application, electron, nwjs

My current App (WPF in Visual Studio) weighs 2MB.

And now I want to re-create this App with Node and Javascript.
Why? Primary reason is - I want to learn some Javascript (yes, this is My way to learning and please dont give me advices how to learn JS). Secondary reason - I want to use full power of CSS3, while WPF App supports only CSS2.

The problem is Weight. Any example App builded with Electron or NWJS weighs about 115MB!!!
I can understand that Desktop App require Node and Browser to work, but 115MB?!

**So my question is** - Is there any way to create Lightweight Desktop App with Electron/NWJS (or similar alternative)?

I can accept final weight about 50-60MB.

Comment: For future visitors, there is a useful blog post on this matter. You might want to check out: https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/reducing-app-distribution-size-in-nwjs-3d5f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only speak for Electron, but 115MB sounds about right for a minimal app, the Chromium content library which Electron is based on is an all or nothing sort of thing and takes up a large chunk of that space.

Comment: I see. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I downvoted in favor of the other answer. This answer is more a recommendation than an actual answer to the question. The other answer provides some possible solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Electron or NW.js are huge in terms of size and required memory, but there are lightweight alternatives: [Libui-node](https://github.com/parro-it/libui-node/) and [Positron](https://github.com/mozilla/positron). Other lightweight platforms not based on node.js are: React-Native, XULRunner and Qt Quick with QML.